# Que estrategia usar para crear aplicacion Offline

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, aplicación-escritorio

Hice una aplicación web ASP.NET (c#) para una empresa minera donde: ingresan datos de trabajo diario y la aplicación genera reportes online. Cuenta con un login, creación de cuentas, etc.

Esta aplicación se ocupa en una oficina con conexión a internet, pero necesitan que les implemente una solución offline para trabajar en una oficina apartada de la ciudad sin conexión.

Me interesaría conocer estrategias o experiencias de ustedes para migrar esta aplicación web a una de escritorio, que una vez que el equipo se conecte a internet, este "suba" la información recaudada a la base de datos.

Comment: Podría trabajar con Datasets, estos permiten trabajar con datos desconectados. Con un TableAdapter luego haría la sincronizacion de los datos.

Comment: deben estar las dos aplicaciones "conectadas"

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Si se trata de un desarrollo web podrias usar la capacidad offline de html5

[Trabaja offline gracias a la API de caché de HTML5](https://www.genbetadev.com/desarrollo-web/trabaja-offline-gracias-a-la-api-de-cache-de-html5)

por supuesto desde el cliente del browser vas a poder detectar cuando estes offline y grabar en una db local provee html5.

En este caso no vas a poder usar eventos de asp.net, sino que deberias usar llamadas ajax quizas con $.ajax de jquery o mejor aun si usas Angular, de esta forma controlas cuando trabajar local o contra el servidor